# There is no sound recognition in module speech_recognition Python

Tags: python, runtime-error, speech-recognition, python-module

Code --

```
import smtplib
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()

try:
  with sr.Microphone() as  source:
    print("Listening...")
    voice = listener.listen(source)
    info = listener.recognize_google(voice)
    print(info)
except:
  print("could not understand")

def send_email():
  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  server.starttls()
  server.login('blah@gmail.com', 'dudeice')
  server.sendmail('blah@gmail.com', 'dudefire@gmail.com', 'Hi')
```

(Email addresses exist in the real code.)
The "Listening..." print statement is run and then the code keeps running but doesn't print the info.

I'm running Windows 64-bit. The Code Editor is Visual Studio Code.

The output:
[image]

Comment: If you have multiple input audio devices on your machine, are you sure SR is listening to the right one and not one that's e.g. just silent?

Comment: @AKX I have only one audio input and output device. So, it has to listen to the required one. I can also see the microphone icon in the taskbar so the microphone _is_ invoked.